# When I play a sound, the speaker makes a 'tick' sound. (on Windows 10)

Tags: windows, audio, speakers

The speaker of my laptop makes a 'tick' sound when I play a video or sound. See information below.

#### Symptoms

1. There is no continuous tick sound, but the sound is played and then a single tick sound is heard.
2. If I turn off the video or sound and play it again a few seconds later, there's no tick sound. However, if I wait several minutes and play it again, I can hear the tick sound.

What is the cause of this sound and how can I stop it?

Comment: Run the manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App.  Get the Manufacturer's Driver Update App and update ALL drivers including BIOS and Chipset. Then if that is not it, have the machine serviced for possible hardware issues.

Comment: Generally, what I do is when I notice some glitch on Windows, wherever possible I run Live Linux USB and see if the issue repeats on Linux. If it doesn’t maybe it’s a soft issue. Was it working fine before or is this a new laptop? Is the issue persistent if you plug in your headphones or external speakers? I had same issue with HP laptop which got fixed after Windows 10 upgrade from 1909 to 2004 and installing the latest audio drivers for 2004.

Comment: @patkim It used to work well, but it started to make tick sound a few weeks ago. And I tried the headset several times but it didn't make a tick sound. Then isn't this a problem with the speakers of my laptop?